# multiprocessing in python moviepy

Tags: python, multiprocessing, moviepy

working on writing video clips as video files in parallel simultaneously on moviepy, without having to wait for the process to complete,

I therefore divide my video into 5-second clips

```
     n=0
     p = 5
     clip = mp.VideoFileClip(videofile).subclip(n, n+p)
```

I then add subtitles to the video,

```
    x = 0
    text2 = 'hello'+str(x)
    text[x] = TextClip(text2, font='Amiri-regular',color='white',fontsize=24).set_duration(p).set_start(0)
```

I then do this again and again for the first five clips, and on the fifth one, I write the clip as a video file

I want to continue processing the rest of the video as the writing continues in the background, so I use multiprocessing, after editing the code suggested by @Roland Smith, I use:

```
if float.is_integer(float(x)/5.0) == True and x != 0:
    text2 = concatenate(text.values())
    textd = text2.on_color(size=(clip.w ,text2.h),color=(0,0,0), col_opacity=0.6).set_pos('bottom')
    video3[n] = CompositeVideoClip([VideoFileClip(videofile).subclip(n,5+n), textd])



def audioclip(data):
    outname = str(data)[-10:].strip('>') + '.mp4'
    data.write_videofile(outname,fps=24, codec='libx264')       
    return outname

names = video3.values()
h = multiprocessing.Pool()
audiofiles = h.map(audioclip, names)
gc.collect()
n = n+p
x = x+1
```

I had imported

```
    from moviepy.editor import *
    import moviepy.editor as mp
    import os 
    import multiprocessing
    from multiprocessing import pool
```

however, I get this error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "p2 (copy).py", line 128, in <module>
audiofiles = h.map(audioclip, names)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
raise self._value
    cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

please help

Comment: I have tried the various recommended suggestions for Pickling Error, but most of them seem to be using classes. I only have the above function in the entire code, any one with a functional example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear, but I thought I'd show you how to do the audio extraction in parallel.

The first code fragment you give chould be reworked into a function.

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
from multiprocessing import pool

def audioclip(input):
    clip = mp.VideoFileClip(input).subclip(0,20)
    outname = input[:-3] + 'mp3'
    clip.audio.write_audiofile(outname)
    return outname
```

Furthermore, you'll need a list of input filenames.
Then using the `map` method of the `multiprocessing.Pool` object, you apply the abovementioned function to all videos.

```
# You should probably take the names from the command line...
names = ['foo.mp4', 'bar.mp4', 'spam.mp4', 'eggs.mp4']

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
audiofiles = p.map(audioclip, names)
```

This will extract audio from the clips in parallel, using as many worker processes as your CPU has cores by default.

**Edit**: Note that if you use `map`, the items of the iterable have to be pickled and sent to the worker process. To prevent this from using a lot of resources it is better to e.g. send the *name* of a big file to the worker process (so it can read the file itself) rather than the *contents* of that file. Otherwise this would fast become a bottleneck in the process. This might look wasteful if multiple workers all have to read the same file, but the filesystem caching that all modern operating systems do should mitigate that.

Comment: hey, used your code to try what I was working on, instead of extracting audio in parallel, I wanted to write the video files in parallel:

Comment: @programmer44 What does `video3.values()` return? It should be an iterable (like a list or tuple) for `map` to work properly

Comment: well, if you look at the if block, you will notice that video3.values() returns the items of the video3 dict,

Comment: @programmer44 That much is obvious. But *what* are the values? (For those of us not familiar with moviepy.) If you are sending complicated objects or large amounts of data to the workers, please read the edit to my answer.

Comment: OK, I see, the values are actually object instances of moviepy's compositevideoclip, and I am actually passing their names, not their values, same error still,

Comment: on second thought, I actually did a print of video3.values()  just before the error message popped up, and turns out i was actually transferring the contents of the objects,

Comment: Try modifying your code so that it passes names to the workers, and let the workers make the subclips. Have the workers return the name of the saved subclips, and use the main program (after the `map`) to combine the clips into a video.

Comment: just tried it, problem is, the videofile is one, hence the second argument that will be passed to p.map() will actually be a single file, instead of a list, and, I am interested in processing different subclips of the same videofile, and I don't know how to combine a while loop with the multiprocessing,

Comment: @programmer44 If the workers need to process a different part of the same file, you can just define the filename inside the worker function, and use a list of tuples of (begin, end) times as the arguments for `map()`.